# Does TCC allow for the creation of static libraries?

Tags: c, static-libraries, tcc

I have been working with the Tiny C Compiler and am trying to create a static library. I have search the TCC documentation but have not found anything about creating a static library. Is creating a static library possible with TCC?

Comment: Static libraries are created using `ar`. The compiler just creates the `.o` files that get put into the library archive.

Comment: @Barmar If you make this an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a static library the same way you do with any other compiler. You generate `.o` files from all the `.c` files, and combine them into a library with the `ar` command.